# Delaying preloadjs for fixed time for testing

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs, preloadjs

Is there a way in `preloadjs` to delay the loading of resources by say 2 seconds just for testing purpose to see the animation in action. As in localhost the files are loaded very quickly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be to use a network throttling tool to simulate low bandwidth. For example, you can do this in [Chrome 38 devtools](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/09/responsive-web-design-with-devtools.html).

If you really wanted to do it in code, it would be trivial to simply delay the start of the load. Something like:

```
var queue = new createjs.PreloadJS();
queue.loadManifest({ ... }, false); // false: don't load immediately
setInterval(function() { queue.load(); }, 2000); // start in 2s
```